# Teaching an Old AI New Magic Tricks

Tags: java, game, ai, libgdx

Recently I wanted to teach the AI of my castle game how to use the spells that I have added to the game. You can try out the game here: [Castleparts](http://playpixelpocalypse.com/castlepartsalpha)

Initially I thought that I would have to add subclasses for each of the four playable races in order to account for the different spells that each one has available. However I ended up coming up with a more generic approach that works just as well.

I'm using the [gdx-ai](https://github.com/libgdx/gdx-ai) library for the AI. Initially (before spells added) the core AI logic looked like this:

```
@Override
public void update(AIPlayerConquer entity) {
    //this is the hierarchy of action priorities
    //when idle, this will be called to search for what state to select next

    //shoot ogres first because they will destroy walls
    entity.findPersons();
    if (entity.shouldAttackPersons()) {
        entity.stateMachine.changeState(SHOOT_PERSONS);
    }

    //shoot if the opponent is aggressive or controls a lot of the map
    else if (entity.isOpponentAggressive() ||
             entity.shouldAttackBasedOnOpponentPercentage() ||
             entity.shouldAttackBasedOnPercentOwned()) {

        entity.stateMachine.changeState(SHOOT);

    //otherwise try to build
    } else {
        entity.stateMachine.changeState(BUILD);
    }
}
```

With just some small changes, I added spells to the core logic. I wanted to put spells at a higher priority than regular actions because they make the gameplay more exciting. Here's the entire class:

```
public enum AIPlayerConquerState implements State<AIPlayerConquer> {
    IDLE,

    SHOOT {
        @Override
        public void enter(AIPlayerConquer entity) {

            entity.findOpponentWallTiles();

            if (!entity.doesOpponentHaveWalls()) {
                entity.stateMachine.changeState(BUILD);
            } else {
                entity.angryAsEnemy();
                entity.tryToShootWalls();
            }

            entity.stateMachine.changeState(IDLE);
        }
    },

    SHOOT_PERSONS {
        @Override
        public void enter(AIPlayerConquer entity) {

            entity.findPersons();

            if (!entity.shouldAttackPersons()) {
                entity.stateMachine.changeState(BUILD);
            } else {
                entity.tryToShootPersons();
            }

            entity.stateMachine.changeState(IDLE);
        }
    },

    BUILD {
        @Override
        public void enter(AIPlayerConquer entity) {
            entity.buildingAsEnemy();
            entity.doActionForConquerGame();

            entity.stateMachine.changeState(IDLE);
        }
    },

    AGGRESIVE_SPELL {
        @Override
        public void enter(AIPlayerConquer entity) {
            entity.tryToCastOffensiveSpell();

            entity.stateMachine.changeState(IDLE);
        }
    },

    DEFENSIVE_SPELL {
        @Override
        public void enter(AIPlayerConquer entity) {
            entity.tryToCastDefensiveSpell();

            entity.stateMachine.changeState(IDLE);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void update(AIPlayerConquer entity) {
        //this is the hierarchy of action priorities
        //when idle, this will be called to search for what state to select next

        //shoot ogres first because they will destroy walls
        entity.findPersons();
        if (entity.shouldAttackPersons()) {
            entity.stateMachine.changeState(SHOOT_PERSONS);
        }

        //shoot if the opponent is aggressive or controls a lot of the map
        else if (entity.isOpponentAggressive() ||
                 entity.shouldAttackBasedOnOpponentPercentage() ||
                 entity.shouldAttackBasedOnPercentOwned()) {

            if (entity.shouldCastSpell(true)) {
                entity.stateMachine.changeState(AGGRESIVE_SPELL);
            } else {
                entity.stateMachine.changeState(SHOOT);
            }

        //otherwise try to build
        } else {
            if (entity.shouldCastSpell(false)) {
                entity.stateMachine.changeState(DEFENSIVE_SPELL);
            } else {
                entity.stateMachine.changeState(BUILD);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void enter(AIPlayerConquer entity) {
    }
    @Override
    public void exit(AIPlayerConquer entity) {
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onMessage(AIPlayerConquer entity, Telegram telegram) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Each AI only has 3 spells available. The next task was to split them up into categories so that some general logic could be applied to decide when to use them.  First I created a type to describe the target of a spell:

```
public enum SpellTarget {

    MY_CRYSTALS,
    MY_WALLS,
    MY_EMPTY_SPACE,
    MY_CANNON,
    OPPONENT_WALLS,
    OPPONENT_EMPTY_SPACE,
    OPPONENT_CANNON;

}
```

Then I added a new field to the `SpellType` enum and gave each spell type a target. Next I split the spells into aggressive and defensive spells by adding this to the `SpellType` enum.

```
public final static List<SpellType> aggresiveSpells = SpellType.getAggresiveSpells();
public final static List<SpellType> defensiveSpells = SpellType.getDefensiveSpells();

private static List<SpellType> getAggresiveSpells() {
    List<SpellType> types = new ArrayList<SpellType>();
    types.add(FIREBALL);
    types.add(FIRE_WALL);
    types.add(SKELETONS);
    types.add(OGRES);
    types.add(LIGHTNING);
    types.add(CANNON_CHARGE);
    types.add(ENERGIZE_CRYSTALS);
    return types;
}

private static List<SpellType> getDefensiveSpells() {
    List<SpellType> types = new ArrayList<SpellType>();
    types.add(SHIELD);
    types.add(STATIC_CHARGE);
    types.add(DIG);
    types.add(SHROUD);
    types.add(BONUS_WALLS);
    return types;
}
```

When the `AIPlayer` class is initialized, the available spells are added to local lists so that they know which spells they have:

```
for (SpellType type : playerType.spells) {
    if (SpellType.aggresiveSpells.contains(type)) {
        this.aggresiveSpells.add(type);
    } else if (SpellType.defensiveSpells.contains(type)) {
        this.defensiveSpells.add(type);
    }
}
```

Some simple code is used to determine whether or not the AI can or should try to cast a spell:

```
protected boolean shouldCastSpell(boolean offensive) {
    if (this.timeSinceSpellCast < this.difficulty.minSecondsBetweenSpells) {
        return false;
    }

    if (offensive) {
        return this.canAffordAggressiveSpell();
    } else {
        return this.canAffordDefensiveSpell();
    }
}

protected boolean canAffordAggressiveSpell() {
    if (this.aggresiveSpells.size() == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    this.spellsReadyToCast = this.getAffordableSpells(this.aggresiveSpells, this.spellsReadyToCast);
    return this.spellsReadyToCast.size() > 0;
}

protected boolean canAffordDefensiveSpell() {
    if (this.defensiveSpells.size() == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    this.spellsReadyToCast = this.getAffordableSpells(this.defensiveSpells, this.spellsReadyToCast);
    return this.spellsReadyToCast.size() > 0;
}

protected List<SpellType> getAffordableSpells(List<SpellType> availableSpells, List<SpellType> canAfford) {
    canAfford.clear();
    for (SpellType type : availableSpells) {
        if (this.hasEnergyForSpell(type)) {
            canAfford.add(type);
        }
    }
    return canAfford;
}
```

And finally, this code is called when the AI actually casts the spell:

```
public void tryToCastOffensiveSpell() {
    this.spellsReadyToCast = this.getAffordableSpells(this.aggresiveSpells, this.spellsReadyToCast);
    if (this.spellsReadyToCast.size() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    this.tryToCastSpell(this.spellsReadyToCast);
}

public void tryToCastDefensiveSpell() {
    this.spellsReadyToCast = this.getAffordableSpells(this.defensiveSpells, this.spellsReadyToCast);
    if (this.spellsReadyToCast.size() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    this.tryToCastSpell(this.spellsReadyToCast);
}

public void tryToCastSpell(List<SpellType> spells) {
    this.timeSinceSpellCast = 0;

    int randomIndex = this.random.nextInt(spells.size());
    SpellType randomSpell = spells.get(randomIndex);

    switch(randomSpell.target) {
    case MY_CANNON:
        this.castSpellOnMyCannon(randomSpell);
        break;
    case MY_CRYSTALS:
        this.castSpellOnMyCrystals(randomSpell);
        break;
    case MY_EMPTY_SPACE:
        this.castSpellOnMyEmptySpace(randomSpell);
        break;
    case MY_WALLS:
        this.castSpellOnMyWalls(randomSpell);
        break;
    case OPPONENT_CANNON:
        this.castSpellOnOpponentCannon(randomSpell);
        break;
    case OPPONENT_EMPTY_SPACE:
        this.castSpellOnOpponentEmpty(randomSpell);
        break;
    case OPPONENT_WALLS:
        this.castSpellOnOpponentWalls(randomSpell);
        break;
    }
}
```

I think that the logic is fairly clear here, but I'm looking for other approaches that might be less verbose, and as always I want to hear about any ways the code can be improved. Thanks!

Also, here is a screenshot of one AI casting spells on another one:

[image: Castleparts Spells]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AIPlayerConquerState` is quite unusual - enums are not meant to hold "business" logic but it seems its enforced by used API.

General: prefer `Collection` over its specializations (List, Set) in public API; it gives you more flexibility for choosing/changing implementations (see below).

`SpellType`: 
1) constants are missing in the post
2) collections will be much more efficient (and safer) when defined as:

```
public final static Collection<SpellType> defensiveSpells = Collections.unmodifiableSet(
        EnumSet.of( SHIELD, STATIC_CHARGE, DIG, SHROUD, BONUS_WALLS ) );
public final static Collection<SpellType> aggresiveSpells
        = Collections.unmodifiableSet( EnumSet.complementOf(defensiveSpells) );
```

Spells collections initialization could be then simplified as (removing both loops):

```
aggresiveSpells = EnumSet.copyOf( playerType.spells ).retainAll( SpellType.aggresiveSpells );
defensiveSpells = EnumSet.copyOf( playerType.spells ).retainAll( SpellType.defensiveSpells );
```

"some simple code" can be simplified (and speed up) further:

```
protected boolean shouldCastSpell(boolean offensive) {
    if (timeSinceSpellCast < difficulty.minSecondsBetweenSpells) {
        return false;
    }
    return offensive ? hasAffordableSpells(aggresiveSpells) : hasAffordableSpells(defensiveSpells);
}

protected boolean hasAffordableSpells(Collection<SpellType> availableSpells) {
    return availableSpells.stream().anyMatch( s -> hasEnergyForSpell(s) );
}
```

The final part can be simplified as well:

```
public void tryToCastOffensiveSpell() {
    List<SpellType> affordableSpells = aggresiveSpells.stream()
            .filter( s -> hasEnergyForSpell(s) )
            .collect( Collectors.toList() );
    if (!affordableSpells.isEmpty()) { tryToCastSpell(affordableSpells); }
}
```

Good luck with casting spells :)